# Chrome Extension -- Content Script is injecting to the popup (React JS)

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to build a chrome extension, I created the popup and it was working normally and create a content script which I tested by changing the body background color which worked, but the background color of the popup also changes

Here is my manifest file

```
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "description": "description",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "permissions": ["storage", "tabs", "activeTab" , "scripting","activeTab"],
  "background": {
  "service_worker": "background/background.js"
},
  "content_scripts": [
{
  "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
  "css": ["/static/css/content_script.css"],
  "js": ["/static/js/content_script.js"]
}
],
  "action": { 
  "default_popup": "index.html"
 }
}
```

And here is my webpack entry:

```
entry: {
  popup: "./src/index.js",
  option: "./src/index.js",
  content_script: "./src/contentScript/content.js",
  background: "./public/background/background.js"
},
```

When I inspect the popup it shows that I get 2 roots, how can I stop the content script from injecting into the popup

[image]